# Returning Value From Child form to parent form is not working

Tags: powershell, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am writing the script which have two forms first form is Form1 which has 3 radio buttons , 1 multi ListBox and second is Form2. What I am trying to achieve that , after selecting desired options and items in listbox it should show form2 with all selection values from Form1 to confirm if all selected values are correct. After getting confirmation selected values should be used in form1 to process something and pass that to another xyz function.

Issue is after getting confirmation from form2 , form1 dont show the selected value as output in $confirmation variable if i want to use that values for further processing. but it shows If I write write-host $confirmation. Not sure what I need to do it here.  Please help.

Below is the Form1 Procced button code

```
## btn_Proceed
$btn_Proceed.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(392, 522)
$btn_Proceed.Name = "btn_Proceed"
$btn_Proceed.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$btn_Proceed.TabIndex = 11
$btn_Proceed.Text = "Proceed"
$btn_Proceed.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true

$btn_Proceed.Add_click({
if($rad_azure.Checked){
$cloud = "Azure"
}
if($rad_aws.Checked){
$cloud = "AWS"
}
if($rad_usa.Checked){
$region = "USA"
}
if($rad_emea.Checked){
$region = "EMEA"
}
if($rad_apac.Checked){
$region = "APAC"
}
if($rad_cio.Checked){
$environment = "CIO Cloud"
}
if($rad_legacy.Checked){
$environment = "Legacy Cloud"
}
if($rad_wave1.Checked){
$wave = "Wave1"
}
if($rad_wave2.Checked){
$wave = "Wave2"
}
if($rad_wave3.Checked){
$wave = "Wave3"
}
if($rad_prepatching.Checked){
$patchingstage = "Pre-Patching"
}
if($rad_postpatching.Checked){
$patchingstage = "Post-Patching"
}
$clients = $lb_available.Items


$Confirmseletion = form-confirmation  -region $region -cloud $cloud -environment $environment -wave $wave -patchingstage $patchingstage -clients $clients

$Confirmseletion

$frm_patching.Close()
})
```

#Below is the Form2 function script

```
function form-confirmation {
param($region, $cloud, $environemnt, $wave, $patchingstage, $clients)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$frm_confirm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$txtb_cloud = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtb_env = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtb_region = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$txtb_wave = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtxb_patching = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$txtb_clients = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$btn_confirm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btn_cancel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
#
# txtb_cloud
#
$txtb_cloud.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(123, 29)
$txtb_cloud.ReadOnly = $true
$txtb_cloud.Name = "txtb_cloud"
$txtb_cloud.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(135, 20)
$txtb_cloud.Text = $cloud
$txtb_cloud.TabIndex = 0
#
# txtb_env
#
$txtb_env.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(123, 61)
$txtb_env.ReadOnly = $true
$txtb_env.Name = "txtb_env"
$txtb_env.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(135, 20)
$txtb_env.Text = $environemnt
$txtb_env.TabIndex = 1
#
# txtb_region
#
$txtb_region.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(123, 94)
$txtb_region.ReadOnly = $true
$txtb_region.Name = "txtb_region"
$txtb_region.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(135, 20)
$txtb_region.Text = $region
$txtb_region.TabIndex = 2
#
# label1
#
$label1.AutoSize = $true
$label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(76, 29)
$label1.Name = "label1"
$label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(34, 13)
$label1.TabIndex = 3
$label1.Text = "Cloud"

#
# label2
#
$label2.AutoSize = $true
$label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(44, 61)
$label2.Name = "label2"
$label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(66, 13)
$label2.TabIndex = 4
$label2.Text = "Environemnt"
#
# label3
#
$label3.AutoSize = $true
$label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(69, 94)
$label3.Name = "label3"
$label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(41, 13)
$label3.TabIndex = 5
$label3.Text = "Region"
#
# label4
#
$label4.AutoSize = $true
$label4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(29, 129)
$label4.Name = "label4"
$label4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(81, 13)
$label4.TabIndex = 6
$label4.Text = "Patching Wave"
#
# label5
#
$label5.AutoSize = $true
$label5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(6, 171)
$label5.Name = "label5"
$label5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(104, 13)
$label5.TabIndex = 7
$label5.Text = "Pre or Post Patching"
#
# label6
#
$label6.AutoSize = $true
$label6.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(318, 29)
$label6.Name = "label6"
$label6.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(38, 13)
$label6.TabIndex = 8
$label6.Text = "Clients"
#
# txtb_wave
#
$txtb_wave.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(123, 129)
$txtb_wave.ReadOnly = $true
$txtb_wave.Name = "txtb_wave"
$txtb_wave.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(135, 20)
$txtb_wave.Text = $wave
$txtb_wave.TabIndex = 9
#
# txtxb_patching
#
$txtxb_patching.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(122, 164)
$txtxb_patching.ReadOnly = $true
$txtxb_patching.Name = "txtxb_patching"
$txtxb_patching.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(135, 20)
$txtxb_patching.Text = $patchingstage
$txtxb_patching.TabIndex = 10
#
# txtb_clients
#
$txtb_clients.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(321, 52)
$txtb_clients.ReadOnly =$true
$txtb_clients.Multiline = $true
$txtb_clients.Name = "txtb_clients"
$txtb_clients.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(223, 132)
for($i=0; $i -lt $clients.Count; $i++){
if(($i + 1) -lt $clients.count){
$txtb_clients.Text += $clients[$i]
$txtb_clients.AppendText("`r`n")
}
else{
$txtb_clients.Text += $clients[$i]
}
}
$txtb_clients.TabIndex = 11
#
# btn_confirm
#
$btn_confirm.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(183, 212)
$btn_confirm.Name = "btn_confirm"
$btn_confirm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$btn_confirm.TabIndex = 12
$btn_confirm.Text = "Confirm"
$btn_confirm.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$btn_confirm.add_click({
    $frm_confirm.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
    $frm_confirm.Close()
    })

#
# btn_cancel
#
$btn_cancel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(321, 212)
$btn_cancel.Name = "btn_cancel"
$btn_cancel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$btn_cancel.TabIndex = 13
$btn_cancel.Text = "Cancel"
$btn_cancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$frm_confirm.CancelButton = $btn_cancel
#
# frm_confirm
#
$frm_confirm.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(578, 279)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($btn_cancel)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($btn_confirm)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($txtb_clients)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($txtxb_patching)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($txtb_wave)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($label6)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($label5)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($label4)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($label3)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($label2)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($label1)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($txtb_region)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($txtb_env)
$frm_confirm.Controls.Add($txtb_cloud)
$frm_confirm.Name = "frm_confirm"
$frm_confirm.Text = "Confirm Selection"
$frm_confirm.TopMost = $true

#$frm_confirm.ShowDialog()
#$frm_confirm.DialogResult.ToString()
if($frm_confirm.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK){
    $inputparam = @{
            'availableAccounts' = $txtb_clients.Text
            'Patchingstage' = $txtxb_patching.Text
            'patchingwave' = $txtb_wave.Text
            'patchingregion' = $txtb_region.Text 
            'patchingenvironemnt' = $txtb_env.Text
            'patchingcloud' =  $txtb_cloud.Text
            }
            
}
return $inputparam
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to expect others to wade through. The following comment offers an explanation that _may_ apply to your situation. If so, we can close your question as a duplicate. If not, please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: In short: Event handlers run in a _child scope_ of the caller, so in order to create or update variables in the caller's scope, the latter must be targeted explicitly, typically with `$script:variable = ...`; without that, you'll implicitly create a _block-local_ variable.
See the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57649395/45375).

Comment: To add to @mklement0’s comments, your problem is this: ```$btn_Proceed.Add_click({
$Confirmseletion = … })``` - the ```$Confirmseletion``` variable only exists **inside** the ```{ … }```. If you want it to be available outside that scope you need to do something else - one option is ```$script:Confirmseletion = …``` per their suggestion.

Comment: There is no different in a WinForm in a c# project and a PS cmdlet.Both work exactly the same.You need to understand how a c# winform works to solve you issue.  First there is a difference between Show() and ShowDialog().The ShowDialog will stay open until the form is closed. Show you can return without an close. A form will automatically dispose on return unless you capture the exit event and and set Cancel to True.  If form gets disposed you cannot read the object in the form. See my c# project for example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net